# Powershell: Unix' col command equivalent to clean up output?

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

What would be a way to remove temporary output from piped `Out-File` in Powershell?

For example, if I run something like:

```
command.exe | Out-File log.txt
```

if a command showed a changing progress bar in terminal:

```
Progress [====================================>                          ]  58%
```

then the captured output in file `log.txt` shows something like this:

```
Progress [=>                          ]  0
Progress [====>                          ]  5
Progress [========>                          ]  10
```

I want it to look in file the same as it shown in terminal.

I'm looking for pretty much the `col` command equivalent from Unix as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778723/redirect-executable-progress-bar-to-log-file) for Bash.

Answer (score 1):

If you have WSL installed, you could try `command.exe | wsl.exe col -b > log.txt`

Otherwise, as a suboptimal ad hoc solution, you could try to filter out the unwanted lines by matching their content:

```
@(command.exe) -notmatch '^Progress \[' | Out-File log.txt
```